# Interacting with PostgreSQL on remote server through SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, postgresql

I have User A setup on my webserver with it's public SSH key copied over to User B's **`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`** over on my database server. The idea is to use an SSH tunnel to facilitate the communication between my web application and remote database. I'm using `ufw` to lock down everything except ssh connections and port **5432** which PostgreSQL uses for local connections:

```
ufw default deny
ufw allow ssh/tcp
ufw allow 5432/tcp
ufw enable
```

Here's the command I use to open the SSH tunnel (via web server):

```
ssh -L 63333:localhost:5432 userb@1.2.3.4
```

Running **`netstat -lpnt | grep 63333 | grep ssh`** after the above command on my web server yields the following:

```
tcp      0     0 127.0.0.1:63333       0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      22560/ssh
tcp6     0     0 ::1:63333             :::*            LISTEN      22560/ssh
```

Next I try and connect to the database server on port **63333** to verify that everything is working:

```
psql -h localhost -p 63333 userb
```

I'm met with the following error message:

> -bash: /usr/bin/psql: No such file or directory

Is there something obvious that I'm missing here? I only have PostgreSQL installed on the database server. From my understanding, once the tunnel is in place, and given the right parameters, shouldn't I have access to the interactive terminal (psql)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh! My SSH tunnel was connecting fine. You need to have a client installed on the server that's establishing the remote connection in order to communicate with PostgreSQL.

In my case it was a one liner on my webserver:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-9.3
```